# Determine the linear transformation type between matrices spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T:M_{2\times3}R\to M_{3\times3}R$ linear transformation

1. Determine if $T$ is onto.
2. $T$ is one-one.

No idea how to solve this.

Comment: Presumably you mean onto, not into. Also, how is the transformation defined (what is $T$ equal to)?

Comment: it's a linear transformation of real matrices that's it there is no more info

Comment: I would suggest using the rank-nullity theorem for vector spaces: $\dim (Ker (T))+\dim (Im (T))=\dim (\Bbb{R}^{2\times 3})=6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$T$ is a linear transformation from a space of matrices isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$ to a space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^9$.

What can you say from this?

Comment: how they are isomorphic if they have different dimension.?

Comment: $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$ and $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^9$.  This is the hint!

Comment: because R^6 is a subset of R^9 it follows that T is one one but not onto is that the full answer?

Comment: Yes, you are right!